# how to to "align justified" 3 responsive horizontal DIVs?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

For a small project, I have created 3 horizontally buttons in a responsive way.
So at wide screens, the buttons are displayed horizontally, next to each other.
And at smaller displays, the buttons are nicely displayed below each other in 1 column.

The code is the following:

```
<style>
.row:after { 
  clear: both; 
}
.row:before, .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; 
}   
@media (min-width: 900px) {
.col { 
  float: left;
  width: 27%; 
}
.button {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 0.75vw;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #BED3EC;
  background: #306BBB;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #458500;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border: 4px solid #AFD283;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
 font-weight:bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
.col { 
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #BED3EC;
  background: #306BBB;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #458500;
  border: 4px solid #AFD283;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
}
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="buttons col" >Initiated by<br><a href="https://www.demeesterzoeterwoude.nl/" class="button"> Yvonne en Winy van der Geest </a></div>
<div class="buttons col" id="button2" >Loved by<br><a href="https://golden-earring.nl/" class="button"> all the Golden Earring fans </a></div>
<div class="buttons col" >Powered by<br><a href="https://www.perspectum.nl/" class="button"> perspectum.nl </a></div>
</div>
```

A codepen [can be found here ...](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/OJbxMgp)

I am happy with the responsive behavior at small screens.
But I would like to have the horizontally displayed divs
to be "justified" across the whole screen, so:
-- the first div is displayed fully to the left;
-- the second div is displayed in the center;
-- and the third div is displayed fully to the right.
Ofcourse the responsive behavior at small screens should remain.

Would highly appreciate some suggestions how to solve.

Comment: Couldn't you use ```justify-content: space-between```?

Comment: I've tried, didn't work ;-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you try to do ?

```css
.row {
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:justify;
}
.col{
  text-align:center;
  text-align-last:center;
  display:inline-block; 
}

.button {
  display:block;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: calc(8px + 0.25vw) ;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #BED3EC;
  background: #306BBB;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col">Initiated by<br><a href="https://www.demeesterzoeterwoude.nl/" class="button"> brother & sister of a family never heard of</a></div>
  <div class=" col" id="button2">Loved by<br><a href="https://golden-earring.nl/" class="button"> all the Golden Earring fans </a></div>
  <div class=" col">Powered by<br><a href="https://www.perspectum.nl/" class="button"> perspectum.nl </a></div>
</div>
```

if yes, inline-block instead float is to be used ... but nowdays, flex is there to make it easy.

```css
.row {display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.col{
  text-align:center; 
}

.button {
  display:block;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: calc(8px + 0.25vw);/* keep a min size */
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #BED3EC;
  background: #306BBB;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col">Initiated by<br><a href="https://www.demeesterzoeterwoude.nl/" class="button"> brother & sister of a family never heard of</a></div>
  <div class=" col" id="button2">Loved by<br><a href="https://golden-earring.nl/" class="button"> all the Golden Earring fans </a></div>
  <div class=" col">Powered by<br><a href="https://www.perspectum.nl/" class="button"> perspectum.nl </a></div>
</div>
```

Finally, a mediaquerie will be needed to reset the layout display

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0.5;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  order: -1
}

.col:nth-child(3) {
  order: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: max-content;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.button {
  flex: 1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: calc(8px + 0.5vw);
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #bed3ec;
  background: #306bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col">Initiated by<br><a href="https://www.demeesterzoeterwoude.nl/" class="button"> brother & sister of a family never heard of</a></div>
  <div class=" col" id="button2">Loved by<br><a href="https://golden-earring.nl/" class="button"> all the Golden Earring fans </a></div>
  <div class=" col">Powered by<br><a href="https://www.perspectum.nl/" class="button"> perspectum.nl </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You offer a very nice solution. Because the left button is fully aligned to the left and the right button is fully aligned to the right, you have solved the justification part. But for optical reasons, all the three buttons should have the same width, as is the case in my initial example. In your solution the width of each button has changed to the width of the text in the button. By the way: thanks for the idea of dealing with the font-size! ...

Comment: @PiotrLinski I updated the last snippet with a compromise from a flex behavior, check it out ;)

Comment: G-Cyrillus: thanks a lot. This is exactly the solution that I have been looking for. Highly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {

  .row{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 
However, when I do that, the 3 buttons stretch to each 33.33% of the screen width,
But I would like that the width of each button stays the same and that "empty space" occurs between the buttons, instead  of the width of each button getting larger ...

Comment: You can put a max-width on your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Display : column** is not the solution for your problem when you have to put your items horizontally, you have to use **display:flex** for your container row and **flex-basis: 20%** for your items to add some margin around your items:

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
.col { 
  float: left;
  width: 20%; 
}
  .row {
     display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
  }
.button {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 0.75vw;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 4px solid #BED3EC;
  background: #306BBB;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #458500;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border: 4px solid #AFD283;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttons {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
 font-weight:bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
}
```

https://codepen.io/boutahlilsoufiane/pen/JjbrGeo

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That already looks much better.
However, ideally:
-- the left button should be displayed fully to the left;
-- and the right button should be displayed fully to the right.